# How to cash out Canadian cheque in foreign country

Tags: check

**Prerequisites:**

- I live in Ukraine
- I don't have a bank account in Canada
- I have a cheque from Canadian bank on my name.
- Ukrainian banks don't cash out cheques.

**Question:**

- How can I cash out the cheque? Is the only way to ask the issuer to change the payment method?
  Is there some international cheque cash out system that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to ask the payer to change the payment method. If the payer insists on only using cheques, consider whether this is a legitimate transaction, because there are quite a few scams surrounding paper cheques.